# remove elements in one list present in another list

Tags: python, list

I have `list1` and `list2`. `list2` is a group of words that have to be removed from `list1`, for example:

```
list1=['paste', 'text', 'text', 'here', 'here', 'here', 'my', 'i', 'i', 'me', 'me']

list2=["i","me"]
```

Desired output:

```
list3=['paste', 'text', 'text', 'here', 'here', 'here', 'my']
```

I have tried different versions using 'for' but no results so far.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Nice, clear, contained and short question, keep up the good questions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> list1 = ['paste', 'text', 'text', 'here', 'here', 'here', 'my', 'i', 'i', 'me', 'me']
>>> list2 = ["i","me"]
>>> list3 = [item for item in list1 if item not in list2]
>>> list3
['paste', 'text', 'text', 'here', 'here', 'here', 'my']
```

NOTE: Lookups in lists are `O(n)`, consider making a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) from `list2` instead - lookups in sets are `O(1)`.

Comment: Always use a list comprehension. Though for someone new to Python I feel like list comprehensions should be explained.

Comment: Note that for just 2 items, making `list2` a `tuple` will out-perform a `set` in most cases...

Comment: as you can tell i'm still learning, i had no clue this could be done, it works like a charm, thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

What about leveraging set arithmetics?

```
diff = set(list1) - set(list2)
result = [o for o in list1 if o in diff]
```

Or even better (more efficient):

```
set2 = set(list2)
result = [o for o in list1 if o not in set2]
```

Comment: It's much less expensive to just check that an element of list1 (without making it a set) is not in a set of list2...

Comment: Would the removal of duplicates in list1 pay for the set overhead? In the example data there are repeated items - where's the breakeven likely to show up?