# Removing sublist from list if it contains given elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this [1]:

```
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c3'], 
 ['a1', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'], 
 ['a1', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c3'], 
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c3'], 
 ['a2', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c3'], 
 ['a2', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]
```

And one like this [2]:

```
[['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2']]
```

And I want to remove sublists of [1] which contain ALL elements in EITHER sublist of [2]. In other words, if a sublist of [1] contains `'a1' and 'b1'` or `'a2' and 'b2'`, it should be removed (only for full matches of the strings).

List [1] should look like this:

```
[['a1', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'], 
 ['a1', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c3'], 
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c3'], 
 ['a2', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]
```

I've tried a similar method to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17934810/6278576

However, I can't figure out how to adapt it to remove sublists from a list when several criteria are met.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function that filters your list for each group of items in your second list.

```
def filterall(list_in, *filter_iterables):
    out = list_in.copy()
    for it in filter_iterables:
        out = [x for x in out if not all(i in x for i in it)]
    return out

x = [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c3'], 
 ['a1', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'], 
 ['a1', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c3'], 
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c3'], 
 ['a2', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c3'], 
 ['a2', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]

filterall(x, ['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2'])
# returns:
[['a1', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'],
 ['a1', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c3'],
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c3'],
 ['a2', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c3'],
 ['a3', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c3'],
 ['a3', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c3'],
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use list comprehension, and just nest your predicates:

```
list1 = [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c3'], 
         ['a1', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'], 
         ['a1', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c3'], 
         ['a2', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c3'], 
         ['a2', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c3'], 
         ['a2', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c3'], 
         ['a3', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c3'], 
         ['a3', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c3'], 
         ['a3', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]
list2 = [['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2']]

print [sublist1 for sublist1 in list1 if not any([all([item2 in sublist1 for item2 in sublist2]) for sublist2 in list2])]
```

Prints for me:

```
[['a1', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'],
 ['a1', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c3'], 
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c3'], 
 ['a2', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c3'], 
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]
```

If you want to run this on larger data (i.e. very long lists), you may want to turn your lists into sets to allow faster intersections.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` + `lambda` + `all` combinations

```
l1 = [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c3'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b3', 'c3'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c3'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c3'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b3', 'c3'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b1', 'c3'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b2', 'c3'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]
l2 = [['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2']]
list(filter(lambda x: all(not all(j in x for j in i) for i in l2), l1))
```

Output:

```
[['a1', 'b2', 'c1'],
 ['a1', 'b2', 'c2'],
 ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'],
 ['a1', 'b3', 'c1'],
 ['a1', 'b3', 'c2'],
 ['a1', 'b3', 'c3'],
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c1'],
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c2'],
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c3'],
 ['a2', 'b3', 'c1'],
 ['a2', 'b3', 'c2'],
 ['a2', 'b3', 'c3'],
 ['a3', 'b1', 'c1'],
 ['a3', 'b1', 'c2'],
 ['a3', 'b1', 'c3'],
 ['a3', 'b2', 'c1'],
 ['a3', 'b2', 'c2'],
 ['a3', 'b2', 'c3'],
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c1'],
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c2'],
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can easily do that with for nested loops ...but my guess is that your teacher is trying to make you think how to optimize it.

I would sort each of the arrays. First each one containing strings and then the top level arrays containing arrays.

With that the task becomes m.log(n) where m is the size of the 2nd array and n is the size of the 1st array.

Is this making sense to you ?